# Using equal-including-properties to compare # string and propertized string

Tags: text-properties, ert

I'm writing some tests for my first emacs package but am running into an issue to do with asserting that two text properties are the same - one that's created with `#` and another with `propertize`:

```
;; this fails
(ert-deftest equal-properties ()
  (should
   (equal-including-properties
    #("Utils" 0 5 (:annotation nil :candidate "type" :meta nil))
    (propertize "Utils" :annotation nil :candidate "type" :meta nil))))
```

In the ert runner, the forms look the same as well:

```
F equal-properties
    (ert-test-failed
     ((should
       (equal-including-properties
        #("Utils" 0 5
          (:meta nil :candidate "type" :annotation nil))
        (propertize "Utils" :annotation nil :candidate "type" :meta nil)))
      :form
      (equal-including-properties
       #("Utils" 0 5
         (:meta nil :candidate "type" :annotation nil))
       #("Utils" 0 5
         (:meta nil :candidate "type" :annotation nil)))
      :value nil))
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated, I'm sure (/I hope) I've missed something simple!

Comment: It's probably related to [Bug#6581 - `equal-including-properties` uses `eq` to compare property values](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6581)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Will get around it for now with custom function then.

Comment: @npostavs or OP: Please consider posting that as an answer. If correct, OP: please consider accepting the answer. Thx.

Comment: @npostavs Happy for you to post that link in an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [Bug#6581 - `equal-including-properties` uses `eq` to compare property values](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6581), hence your `:candidate "type"` property string values may compare non-`eq`.  If you byte compile the test code, you might find it works because the compiler coalesces string literals (e.g., [Bug#31688](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31688)).

You could consider using a symbol instead of a string, if that makes sense for your purposes:

```
#("Utils" 0 5 (:meta nil :candidate type :annotation nil))
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the suggestion for using a symbol - I'll look into that. Right now I am getting around this for just my use case with

`(defun text-property-equal (t1 t2)
  (and (equal
        (text-properties-at 0 t1)
        (text-properties-at 0 t2))
       (string= t1 t2)))`